# How do I configure doctrine 2 so that it can find the setup.php file?

Tags: doctrine-orm

1. When I execute:

   ```
   doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   '"@php_bin@"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
   ```

   I fixed this by changing bin\doctrine.php to be this:

   ```
   php "C:\Program Files\DoctrineORM-2.2.2\bin\doctrine.php" %*
   ```
2. Now, I get farther.  While executing the following from the command line:

   ```
   doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
   ```

   part of the output is as follows:

   ```
   Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in  C:\Users\bam1216\Documents\Development\DoctrineTutorial\project\bootstrap_doctrine.php on line 7
   ```

   The file that fails is line 7 of bootstrap_doctrine.php, which is the require_once line below:

   ```
   use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

   require_once "Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php";
   ```

   The Setup.php that it refers to is located on my machine at C:\Program Files\DoctrineORM-2.2.2\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup.php.  How can I configure it to find that setup file?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the include path for PHP.  I added the following lines to the beginning of bootstrap_doctrine.php:

```
$path = 'C:\Program Files\DoctrineORM-2.2.2';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```